# How to show like GridView GUI by HTML+CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am porting Firefox addon to Chrome extension and want to use GridView like following on option window.
[image: Firefox addon grid]

However, on chrome extension option.html, such GUI cannot be used and only HTML+CSS can be used.

`select` tag is not solution because multiple columns can't be used.
How can I make gui by HTML+CSS which multiple columns and selecting by row is possible?

Comment: You can also use javascript, therefor, you can use plugins for sortable tables with sticky header and row selectable such as https://datatables.net/

Comment: Thank you. I'm also taught https://jspreadsheets.com by other user. I'm going to try various libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/) from [jspreadsheets](https://jspreadsheets.com/) because it has date sort and appropriate events.

P.S.
As of 2020 August, w2ui cannot used for Chrome extension.